# More article style Q&A question format?

Tags: feature-request, questions, self-answer, instant-self-answer

As you know, when you ask your question on Stack Exchange you can, then and there, answer it yourself as well. I had a major issue with iframes in [iOS Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#iOS-specific_features). I found the solution, and my boss wanted me to detail the problem and solution so other developers in our company could avoid it as well.

Well, I thought I'd do it through Stack Exchange and share my results with the wider web as well, but this happened:

[How to get an IFrame to be responsive in iOS Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083462/how-to-get-an-iframe-to-be-responsive-in-ios-safari/23083735#23083735)

I really expected no one to answer the question, but some one did and my answer was pushed down.

So I have two problems with this:

1. It took me three hours to write this, and I intended the question and answer to be read in sequence. In essence you can criticise this and say I wrote an article, but you try to come up with good question for something like this, especially when you already know the answer. This was the best I could think of. State the problem in the question & state the solution in the answer. But it's still intended to be read as a continuous text, more like an article than anything else.
2. The second issue is, that the answer given by the other user is incorrect. I tested it, and now there is this incorrect answer between my question and correct answer that was intended to be read in sequence with the question.

So I would like to propose this.

- When a Q&A style question is posted, the OPs will remain together unless another answer has more up votes. In fact, I would think it would be more correct for them to remain together permanently unless the OP answer receives down votes, but I do not think that would fly well on Stack Exchange.
- When a Q&A style question is posted, the OP's answer will be automatically accepted. When something like this is done, the OP already is the correct answer. It's possible that someone will give a better answer, but if that happens the accepted answer can simply be replaced not to mention it's highly unlikely for something like that to happen. I think this would make sense, because this would discourage (and yes I know, taboo) answering half ass answers like the one I got. When someone answers an already accepted question they always put more thought into it and basically keeps down noise. And yes, I am using the term noise here, because when the Q&A is posted it's usually with a good solution that works.

Comment: While I aplaud your effort (seriously self answered questions are often the best) if you can't frame a good question for your answer it's usually a sign that this is the wrong format for it; as you have found

Comment: Although you seem to have done a fine job of it in this case. I'm not sure I see the problem here. If the other answer is wrong downvote and/or comment

Comment: You can accept your own answer (I think after some time has passed), but also realize that unlike regular accepted answers, self-accepted answers don't float to the top.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your question and answer need to be read together *then you're doing it wrong*.  This is a Question and Answer site, not a site where people post articles.  Your question and answer should be reasonably independent.

The question should be a good question on its own merits.  People should read that and feel that it is a clear, appropriately scoped, on topic, and well researched question without even knowing that you answered it.  When reading the answer it should read like an understandable, correct, *helpful*, and detailed answer to the question; there should be no need to *know* that the question's author wrote it.

We don't *want* to discourage additional answers.  Just because you already have found an answer doesn't mean nobody else can write a better one.  I've seen plenty of self answered questions where someone else came along and provided a much better quality answer than one posted by the question author.

If someone posts a low quality/incorrect answer to your self answered question then you should treat it just the same as you'd treat any other low quality/incorrect answer you come across.  Downvote it, and consider commenting with what's wrong with it.  If it is sufficiently low quality or otherwise problematic enough to merit moderator action (being just wrong is *not* grounds for moderator intervention) then flag the post as appropriate.

Comment: And if people couldn't downvote because of their low reputation - you couldn't force them to gain more reputation (there's no rule) nor you couldn't treat anyone as you treat yourself - we're all different. Some of us are writers and after a good (mb yearly time) they realize themselves here non-matching to the community. Non-mathing creative people could very long be underfimed and not very sure where they are (non natives ..etc). But after considerable banning, surveillance, pressure on them they could put their hands up to retreat unfamely and failured years of work and discarded edits, wit

Comment: @Xsi I'm not sure what the point of that comment is.

Comment: How do you show research effort in a question if the research you did consisted of actually finding the answer (which was posted as an answer)? It's illogical to do any research beyond finding the answer, so there likely isn't much to show in the question, and often research effort is just a way to show you aren't asking for someone to do your work without you having tried at all, which doesn't really apply to self-answered questions.

Comment: @Dukeling That is a part of what makes self answered questions hard, and why most people end up doing a bad job of posting them, and yet it *is* still important for the question posted to be a high quality question that stands on its own merits.  You shouldn't just throw up a crap question as a placeholder for a tutorial style answer.  Generally this would mean finding some reasonable cut off point, the point at which people are likely to struggle most, at which the research shown in the question stops, and the research is continued to its conclusion in the answer.